# Array - ajax to Symfony

Tags: jquery, arrays, symfony

How to get in Symfony an array post by ajax request in jquery ?

I did that :

My jquery (array + ajax request):

```
var array_data_file = [];
array_data_file['locale'] = $(this).data('locale');
array_data_file['domain'] = $(this).data('domain');
array_data_file['bundle'] = $(this).data('bundleName');
array_data_file['content'] = textTrad;

$.ajax({
        url: Routing.generate(locale + '__RG__new_translation'),
        data: array_data_file,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

my php:

```
public function newTraductionAction(Request $request)
    {              
        $array_file = $this->get("request")->getContent();
        var_dump($array_file); die;
    }
```

My alert show 'null' ...

thanks for your help (I'm a noob...)

Comment: this really shouldn't be hard to research, you need to send as json using `json_encode()` also need to echo the url , php and javascript run in different environments. Please learn to use browser console to troubleshoot errors and inspect ajax requests

Comment: Try `$this->get('request')->get('locale')`

Comment: try to change `data: array_file` into `data: array_data_file` you have forgot the name

Comment: @charlietfl : In my console Ihaven't error.

Comment: @Matteo : same problem... "null"

Comment: @napster3world: I changed it but same thing ... "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code:

my array became an object

```
var array_data_file = {};
```

my ajax function:

```
function new_trad(array_data_file) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Routing.generate(locale + '__RG__new_translation'),
        data: {data_array:array_data_file},
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and side PHP:

```
public function newTraductionAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $array_file = $request->request->get('data_array');

       var_dump($array_file);  die;
}
```